# RegionPlot empty when equation is returned from Solve

Tags: plotting

I have two concentric cones, one slightly bigger than the other and I want to plot their conic sections in 2D intersecting them with the same plane. I want to plot the contour of the inner conic and fill the area in between like

```
eq1 = 25 ((i - 0.00237 j)^2 + (-0.00237 i + 0.928 j)^2) - (-4.94 + 
     0.01229 i + 0.37 j)^2;
eq2 = 25 ((i - 0.00237 j)^2 + ( -0.00237 i + 0.928 j)^2) - (-5.9598 + 
     0.01229 i + 0.37 j)^2;

Show[{
  RegionPlot[
   {eq1 > 0 && eq2 < 0},
   {i, -2, 2}, {j, -2, 2}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Lighter[Green, 0.8]],
  ContourPlot[eq1 == 0, {i, -2, 2}, {j, -2, 2}, ContourStyle -> Orange]
  }]
```

[image]

The problem is that `eq1` and `eq2` are not given by hand like in the example above but are the result of the following function

```
getConicSection[cone_, toPlaneCoordinates_] := 
  Module[{h, R, cx, cy, cz, rotatedCone},
   (* Get the cone equation in the plane coordinate system *)
   h = cone["distanceToApex"];
   R = cone["bottomRadius"];
   {cx, cy, cz} = cone["bottomPosition"];
   rotatedCone = ((x - cx)^2 + (y - cy)^2)/(R/h)^2 - (z - cz - 
        h)^2 /. Solve[{i, j, k} == toPlaneCoordinates[{x, y, z}], {x, 
       y, z}];
   (* When k=0 we get the conic *)
   rotatedCone /. k -> 0
   ];
```

If I do so the `ContourPlot` still works but the `RegionPlot` is empty.

[image]

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

(Mathematica 10.1 in Win7)

---

A more minimal example

```
getEq[n_] := Module[{eq, newEq},
   eq = If[n == 1,
     25 ((x - 0.00237 y)^2 + (-0.00237 x + 0.928 y)^2) - (-4.94 + 
        0.01229 x + 0.37 y)^2,
     25 ((x - 0.00237 y)^2 + ( -0.00237 x + 0.928 y)^2) - (-5.9598 + 
        0.01229 x + 0.37 y)^2];
   newEq = eq /. Solve[{i == x, y - k == j}, {x, y}];
   newEq /. k -> 0
   ];

eq1 = getEq[1];
eq2 = getEq[2];

Show[{
  RegionPlot[
   {eq1 > 0 && eq2 < 0},
   {i, -2, 2}, {j, -2, 2}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Lighter[Green, 0.8]],
  ContourPlot[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {i, -2, 2}, {j, -2, 2}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Orange, Green}]
  }]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `eq1` from the first example is different than your `eq1 = getEq[1];`, in the second case you are returning a list with one element, take the `First` and it will work as you expected. Doing:

```
eq1 = First@getEq[1];
eq2 = First@getEq[2];
```

Fixes your example.

Comment: Beat me by seconds.

Comment: But your answer is nicer, includes images!

Comment: That's why you beat me. I was about to suggest using `First` within his functions when I saw the "new answer".

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty is that `getEq` returns a `List`, e.g.

```
getEq[1]
(*
 {25 ((i - 0.00237 j)^2 + (-0.00237 i + 0.928 j)^2) 
  - (-4.94 + 0.01229 i + 0.37 j)^2}
*)
```

So, the inequalities do not make sense. The solution is to simply pull out the formulas, e.g.

```
eq1 = getEq[1][[1]];
eq2 = getEq[2][[1]];
```

Then it plots correctly

[image]